# Solution Nielsen and Chuang exercize 10.71

Tags: measurement, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, fault-tolerance

> **Exercise 10.71:** Verify that when $M = e^{−iπ/4}SX$ the procedure we
> have described gives a fault-tolerant method for measuring $M$.

The book describes a procedure to perform the measurement. Instead of pasting and copying it, I made a drawing of that circuit to avoid complications (note that I drew only 3 qubits to encode each block of qubits, but they should be 7, so please consider 7 qubits instead on 3).

[image: Circuit to measure M]

Does anyone know how to show that this circuit perform a fault-tolerant measure of M?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I found the solution, I attach it (it is in italian):

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. What is your question?

Comment: I don't know how to demonstrate that I can perform a measurement of M with the procedure described in the text. 
I know that I have to replace the controlled-M gates in the figure with controlled-ZSX gates transversally for each pair of qubits in the ancilla and the code and apply 7 gates transversally to the ancilla qubits, but when I do it, I don't get the right result.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please modify your question accordingly? It is a rule of this site that each question has to contain what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, I modified it drawing the actual circuit which should be used to perform the measurement of M.

Comment: @Maria , Please post the answer separately instead of editing it into the question. Also, accept your own answer. This will help others looking for the same question in finding the answer.